# Select row with id, unless it has parent, than select that one

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with articles and stock information (two tables). When entering the article id, I select the article from the article table, do some other stuff and then look in the stock table if the article is available.

This could be an easy peasy `SELECT * FROM articles`, BUT: my `articles` table has a field `parent_id`. If that is set, I should select the parent row. Let me illustrate:

```
+----+-----------+---------+---------+
| id | parent_id | article | country |
|----|-----------|---------|---------+
|  1 |           | abc     | uk      |
|  2 |           | cde     | us      |
|  3 |           | efg     | can     |
|  4 | 6         | hij     | mex     |
|  5 |           | klm     | bra     |
|  6 |           | nop     | us      |
|  7 | 8         | qrs     | mex     |
|  8 |           | tuv     | uk      |
+----+-----------+---------+---------+
```

If I search for article `abc`, it should return row 1 with country UK. If I'm searching for `hij`, the query should return row 6, with country US instead of row 4, with country mex. Is there any way of doing this in MySQL or is it faster/better/the only way to split it up in two queries with PHP?

Comment: This is totally inconsistent - if I query for `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = 4`, it would return different results based on the state of the field, without being able to guess why. Just select everything joined with the parent, and make decisions PHP-wise.

Comment: I don't see it that way. There's one single, very specific reason why I need to select the parent row. So I don't see why I shouldn't do it in SQL if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `LEFT` outer join:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(p.id, a.id) AS id
  , COALESCE(p.country, a.country) AS country 
FROM 
        articles AS a
    LEFT JOIN 
        articles AS p
            ON p.id = a.parent_id 
WHERE
    a.article LIKE '%hij%' ;          -- or:  a.article = 'hij'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using mysql IF Conditionals [Mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html)

However you can rapidly end up with an evil sql statement that is hard to debug.  You're probably quicker / easier to resolve using multiple queries and php if's.

There's an alternative option of you could write a view or a stored proc to achieve it for you but again questionable on benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MySQL [if function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html) I think the IFNULL is the function you're after.

```
IFNULL(parent_id, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT JOIN
SELECT     a2.id, a2.country
FROM       articles a1
LEFT JOIN  articles a2 ON (a2.id = a1.parent_id)
WHERE      a1.article  = 'hij';